# For instance uut/A1/, width 1 of formal port S is not equal to width 4 of actual signal in1

Tags: verilog

Can anyone tell why I am getting these warnings?

> For instance uut/A1/, width 1 of formal port S is not equal to width 4
> of actual signal in1.
>
> For instance uut/A1/, width 1 of formal port Cout is not equal to
> width 4 of actual signal in2.
>
> For instance uut/A1/, width 1 of formal port A is not equal to width 4
> of actual signal s1.
>
> For instance uut/A2/, width 1 of formal port S is not equal to width 4
> of actual signal in3.
>
> For instance uut/A2/, width 1 of formal port Cout is not equal to
> width 4 of actual signal in4.
>
> For instance uut/A2/, width 1 of formal port A is not equal to width 4
> of actual signal s2.

```
module binary(A,B,P);
input [2:0]A;
input [3:0]B;
output [6:0]P;
wire c1,c2;
wire [3:0]s1,in1,in2,in3,in4,s2;

assign in1[0] = A[0] & B[1];
assign in1[1] = A[0] & B[2];
assign in1[2] = A[0] & B[3];

assign in2[0] = A[1] & B[0];
assign in2[1] = A[1] & B[1];
assign in2[2] = A[1] & B[2];
assign in2[3] = A[1] & B[3];

assign in3[0] = A[2] & B[0];
assign in3[1] = A[2] & B[1];
assign in3[2] = A[2] & B[2];
assign in3[3] = A[2] & B[3];

FA A1(in1,in2,s1,c1);
assign in4[0] = s1[1];
assign in4[1] = s1[2];
assign in4[2] = s1[3];
assign in4[3] = c1;

FA A2(in3,in4,s2,c2);
assign P[0] = A[0] & B[0];
assign P[1] = s1[0];
assign P[2] = s2[0];
assign P[3] = s2[1];
assign P[4] = s2[2];
assign P[5] = s2[3];
assign P[6] = c2;

endmodule


module FA(S, Cout, A, B, Cin);
output S;
  output Cout;
  input  A;
  input  B;
  input  Cin;

  wire   w1;
  wire   w2;
  wire   w3;
  wire   w4;

  xor(w1, A, B);
  xor(S, Cin, w1);
  and(w2, A, B);   
  and(w3, A, Cin);
  and(w4, B, Cin);   
  or(Cout, w2, w3, w4);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the `S` `output` port of the `FA` module as a 1-bit signal:

```
module FA(S, Cout, A, B, Cin);
output S;
```

Inside `module binary`, you declared `in1` as a 4-bit signal:

```
wire [3:0]s1,in1,
```

Then you connected a 4-bit signal (`in1`) to a 1-bit port (`S`):

```
//     S
FA A1(in1,in2,s1,c1);
```

Since this is an unusual thing to do, your tool is doing the correct thing by issuing a warning message.

The width of the signal should match the width of the port.  Based on your design requirements, you must decide which bit of `in1` to connect to `S`.  For example,

```
FA A1(in1[0],in2,s1,c1);
```

The same applies for the other warnings as well.